# Moving neo4j database from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: linux, database, windows, ubuntu, neo4j

I created neo4j database using cypher queries through browser and some python (py2neo) routines.

Now, I have to transfer this database to another neo4j instance on my Linux desktop.

What I did-

1. Zip the contents of folder **default.graphdb**.
2. Unzipped the contents of the zip file to data/graph.db in my linux installation.

Also the user:pass of the database are same.

But when I goto the browser, I can't find any of that data. The directory does point to the folder that I extracted to (/home/goelakash/neo4j-community-2.3.0/data/graph.db).

How do I get that database?

EDIT - messages.log

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3JPglmAz1b5ak1vRWR5Z0p5UVE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

The data files should be located directly in `data/graph.db`. So check e.g. if there is a file called `neostore.nodestore.db`. If so, check the permissions - the system user running Neo4j needs to have full recursive read/write permission on the graph.db folder.
Also make sure that you're using the same version of Neo4j on Windows and Linux (or upgrade the store following the reference manual).
For more insight attach the startup sequence form `data/graph.db/messages.log`.

Comment: I have added the messages.log file